How to filter metadata where data inside the metadata has multiple id's stored as giant string with comma separated
I am using Chroma from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma According to chroma's doc, it only allows $eq, $in etc for metadata filed.
the metadata is structured as
 {
    userids: '217cdc91-dssd-fasd,3850d-sdsw-150, 217cdc91-dssd-fasd',
    created: 1725908639288,
    description: 'GitHub Pull Requests data',
  }

i want to retrieve documents if i mentioned user id present in the userids using collection.query metadata filters
for reference i looked this documentation
how to figure out a method to retrieve the data if any one id matches within the userids

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
